# I need multiple sets of settings. Is this possible with Android or should I roll my own settings implementation?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, sharedpreferences, xamarin

I'm working on a monitoring system that can accommodate many `Sites`. A `Site` is defined by an `ID` and `Password`, as well as some boolean options.

It's fairly easy to manage one site with the settings. I can use `PreferenceManager` to get the Default Shared Preferences for a `Context`, and each setting is identified by a `string Key`. But is it possible to have multiple sets of settings? E.g. for each `Site` to have its own set of settings?

If not, should I bypass the PreferencesManager and store settings for each site in a Sqlite database?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Properties](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/java/util/Properties.html) and create activity manually